# pass data to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an Activity and a simple fragment ,I try to use Bundle to pass data to the fragment, but the bundle is always null.
I can't figure out what is the problem?!

this is my Activity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FragmentA fragmentA =new FragmentA();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name","Ahmed Ezzat");
        fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    public void showFragment(View view) {

        FragmentA fragmentA=new FragmentA();
        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.dumper,fragmentA,"fragment A");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

and this is my fragment class

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
TextView textView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);

    textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment);


    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String name = bundle.getString("name");
    if (name!=null){
    textView.setText(name);}

    return view;
}
```

}

any help?

Comment: You have two instances of `FragmentA` above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called `setArguments` in the `showFragment` method.

The Fragment in the `onCreate` method is never used.

You may try using the following code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showFragment(View view) {

        FragmentA fragmentA=new FragmentA();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name","Ahmed Ezzat");
        fragmentA.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.dumper,fragmentA,"fragment A")
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the fragment when building the fragment, then passing it to the transaction.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
TextView textView;

String message;

public FragmentA(String message){
    this.message = message;
    }

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);

textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment);

textView.setText(message);

return view;
}
```

And when attaching, you just pass it in the constructor.